# Как задать активную область ссылки на изображении в html/css?

Tags: html, css

На веб-странице есть три иконки платёжных систем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с таким кодом:

html:

```
<div class="paicons">
<a href="#" title="mastercard"><img src="master.png"></a>

<a href="#" title="Visa"><img src="visa.png"></a>

<a href="#" title="PayPal"><img src="pal.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.paicons {
padding: 1em;
float: right;
margin-top: -10em;
margin-right: 28em;
}
```

При этом при наведении курсора на картинки не вся область является ссылкой,
а только около половины, вот что показывает браузер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался задать ширину и высоту элементу "a" в css внутри "div" но это не дало результата. Как сделать так чтоб каждая ссылка была точно подогнана под картинку? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  height: 6em;
  background: antiquewhite;
  text-align: center;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="paicons"><!-- здесь нет пробела между тегами
  --><a href="#" title="mastercard"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=MasterCard&w=100&h=50"></a>
  <a href="#" title="Visa"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=Visa&w=100&h=50"></a>
  <a href="#" title="PayPal"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=16&txt=PayPal&w=100&h=50"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.paicons a{
display:inline-block}
```

попробуйте